# java programing with hardware

Tags: java, hardware

just wanted to know if it is possible to send interrupts to a java code which is running in background or foreground(with no console), whenever there is a key stroke

Comment: What? Can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: key stroke from where ? From any programm running or another Java programm.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean, can the console be used in a non-line-buffering mode?

In that case, you can't do it with pure Java. You can do it with a fairly simple JNI library and if you google there may be an open source one available.